# Get last added element Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

How can we get the last **added** element in ArrayList. I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687833/how-to-get-the-last-value-of-arraylist) that explain how to get the last element, but is the last added element always the last element ?

Comment: If you use `add(element)` yes as it "Appends the specified element to the end of this list.", if you use `add(index, element)` it can be anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes for `ArrayList`, It preserves the order of insertion

If you explicitly add the element at particular position by specifying index [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29), in this case you need to set insertion time by customizing ArrayList implementation and while retrieving the latest inserted element consider that time in calculation

or better have a reference pointing to last inserted item as  [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) suggested, also maintain it on removal

Better thing would be use `LinkedHashSet`, if you are not concerned about uniqueness property of set

Comment: Unless you tell it otherwise with `add(index, element)`

Comment: No insertion time needed, that would be overkill; just keep record of the last element added. But this works only if you have the class under your control; judging from OP's question it seems like he's dealing with a pre-existing `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Marko yes that would be better

Comment: ...except if you also want to support the case where elements are *removed* and you still want the last element added! Then something like your solution would be the only option, but still not keeping time, but sequence of addition operation. Otherwise it would be almost typical to see the same addition time for many elements added is rapid succession.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, as the other people said, `ArrayList` preserves insert order. If you want the last added element, (only if you always add your elements with `add(element)`) just type this:

```
yourArrayList.get(yourArrayList.size()-1);
```

Your answer is in the link that you said :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `add(element)` signature, your last element in `ArrayList` always be last inserted element.

If you are using `add(index, element)` you can't know exactly which is last one. Simplest solution to create your subclass of `ArrayList` that will hold last inserted element in special variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [adding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#add(E)) to a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) without specifying an index will append the element at the end.

### `getLast`

In Java 21+, every `List` inherits a convenient [`getLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#getLast()) method from the [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) interface. For details, see [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

```
List< String > letters = new ArrayList<>( List.of( "a" , "b" , "c" ) );
letters.add( "d" ) ;
String lastAddedLetter = letters.getLast() ;
```

> lastAddedLetter = "d"