# Get index of newly added item in a list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to get the index of a newly added element into an arraylist. e.g.

```
List listA = new ArrayList();

// Lots of code adding and removing things from `listA`, imagine `listA` now 
// contains approx 10,000 records

listA.add("element 0");
```

How do I find out the index of the newly added item?

I think that perhaps, I need a different data structure, but cannot think of what to use.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to know this index value? It hints to me that you might be doing something the wrong way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first element added to the list would have index 0.
The last element added would have the index `listA.size()-1`.
However, you should note that if you remove elements from the list, some of the indices (indices of elements that had higher index than the removed element) would change. For example, if you remove the n'th element, the former (n+1)'th element would become the n'th element.

Thanks talex for the comment. I forgot about `indexOf()`, which returns the index of the supplied element (if that element is found in the list). However, this requires linear search time.

If you wish to treat the indices of the list as keys to find the values stored in the list, you might be better off using a `HashMap<Integer,String>`.

Comment: And you can use `indexOf` method.

Comment: OK, I would be removing elements from the list, so that would be a problem.

I could just not bother removing the elements, but that seems bad coding...

Is there any other data structure that I could remove items from whilst preserving an index to access the items by?

Comment: Also keep in mind this won't work if (ab)using [`set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-)

Comment: Hashmap does seem the way forward.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The index will be `size()`, just get it *before* adding:

```
List listA = new ArrayList();
...
int index = listA.size();

listA.add("element 0"); // "element 0" will be at the "index" item
```

Answer (score 1):

You may retrieve index of any element in your list using `indexOf` method :

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();

//Lots of code adding and removing things from listA, imagine listA now contains approx 10,000 records

String str = "element 0"
listA.add(str);

int index = listA.indexOf(str)
```

If you are only concerned by the index of the last element, the list javadoc says : "   add(E e)
Appends the specified element to the end of this list (optional operation)."

so you can use :

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();

//Lots of code adding and removing things from listA, imagine listA now contains approx 10,000 records

listA.add("element 0");

int index = listA.size()-1 //minus 1 because index start at 0
```

As you seem concerned to access element by index ( identifier ?) you should take a look at Map :

```
Map<int, String> mymap = new HashMap<int, String>();
mymap.add(1, "element1");
mymap.add(2, "element2");
mymap.add(3, "element3");

mymap.get(3);//return "element3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List listA = new ArrayList();

String a = "element 0";

listA.add(a);

int index = listA.indexOf(a);
```

there you go

Comment: Your solution could be time cousuming if listA contains a lot of items; another issue is that if ListA contains the same items

Comment: Well I always thought ArrayList is meant for fast retrieving values. I don't know how big it would have to be to make it slow...

Comment: @Lucas The implementation of `indexOf` will have to loop through the entire list, looking for a matching item. This will be slow compared with other approaches of finding the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `add(element)` order is preserved so the last element in the List will be the most recently add one. 
So you can use `listA.get(listA.size-1);`

If you are using `add(index,element)` this will not be the case as **order is not preserved.**

See here for related question [How to get the last value of an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687833/how-to-get-the-last-value-of-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

Index of a `List` starts with `0` and ends with `size()-1`.

If you calculate number of elements, it would be same of `size()-1`.

For example if your list contains 100 records, then index of last element will be `size()-1` which is 99.

```
List listA = new ArrayList();
int lastIndex=listA.size()-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

unlike what other suggest....`size()` gives the total size of the `List` and since `List` indexes are zero based so `size() - 1` gives the index of the last element int he list.

Don't confuse the ;ast element as the element you just added. As long as we user the `add()` method new elements get appended to the list at the end, but list also has another add method which takes the index as an argument. Using this method you can add the new element anywhere in the list. In that case `size() - 1` would not give you the index of the latest added element.