# How to add an element to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, methods

how can i make a user enter a number, which will then shift the array to the right 1. the array cant exceed 50. please help, thanks in advance :)

```
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(1);
    public void add(int value) {

      list.add(0, value);
      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         list.add(index, value); // how to make the elements shift to the right?
         if(list.size > 50) {
           list.remove(50);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to add in the middle of your list?

Comment: how am i adding in the middle of the list?

Comment: array != `ArrayList`

Comment: Where is `index` defined?

Comment: @user2878551, so for `[0,1,...,49]` with index `1` and number `99` you want `[0,99,1,...,48]`. Is this correct?

Comment: is there any specific reason you want to go for an array. It appears `java.util.LinkedList` is a better choice for you, Add the elements to the head `addFirst()`

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` shifts elements for you, that's why it has `index`, [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430247/why-start-an-arraylist-with-an-initial-capacity).

When you create the `ArrayList`: `new ArrayList<Integer>(50)`  `50` dont define  `size`, define `capacity` of the `ArrayList`. When created is empty and size is 0.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(50);


public void add(int value) {
  if (list.size <= 50) list.remove(list.size() - 1);

  // inserting element at position 0 shifts other elements
  list.add(0, value);

}
```

Comment: you don't understand the constructor parameter `initialCapacity`. You were correct before.

Comment: oh wow really? it was that easy? thought of that but i was like surely its a bit harder

Comment: If he use array rather than collections as List, he should handle this manually.

Comment: ArrayLists grow, that's the problem, the parameter `50` is just the initial size.

Comment: @weston you mean that initial capacity is getting larger when the list has not enough space? So this answer is not true.

Comment: @weston In this case 50 is just the reserved memory for that ArrayList but later it can grow up, isn't?

Comment: @Drumnbass yes, my comments relate to when he was not removing anything.

Comment: You set size to 50, but at some point this arraylist will contain 51 (before the remove). Therefore it will have to resize, so you've tried to be efficient, but it's caused more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(50);

  public void add(int value) {
     if (list.size() == 50)
         list.remove(list.size() -1);

     list.add(value);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!! also do you know how i can get the last value of the list. for example if there were 11 elements inside the 50 size list. how would i get the vale of the 11th element?

Comment: list.size() -1 gives you the last element's index.

Comment: You know you are adding new elements at the end of the ArrayList, right? not at the beginning as the OP asked.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TestList {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(4);

   // use add() method to add elements in the list
   arrlist.add(15);
   arrlist.add(4);
   arrlist.add(5);

   // adding element 25 at third position
   arrlist.add(2,25);

   for (Integer number : arrlist) {
   System.out.println("List Value = " + number);
   }  
   }
}
```

Comment: do you know how i can get the last value of the list. for example if there were 11 elements inside the 50 size list. how would i get the vale of the 11th element?

Comment: @BriannaXD size() of the list gives you the number of elements; since the indexes start in 0, you can `listName.get(listName.size() - 1)` to get the last value stored in the list `listName`. You could just asked StackOverflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/687842/5108777]

Answer (score -1):

Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices). From this "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html"

so you need just to check if the size of your list is no longer than 50, and add the number in the specified index.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(50);

  public void add(int value) {

     if (list.size() == 50) // if the size of the array is 50, then remove the last value.
     list.remove(list.size() -1);

     list.add(int index, E element);// you can even choose where position to insert your value.
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In the constructor part what you have defined is the capacity. The default minimum capacity is 10. You know your array cant exceed to 50. There is a chance that there must be less element then 50. So first remain that constructor part empty.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public void add(int value) {
        if(list.size() <50)
            list.add(0,value);
            else
            {
                list.remove(list.size()-1);
                list.add(0, value);
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(51);

public void add(int value) {
  list.add(0, value); //other elements are shifted right, you need do nothing else

  //then limit the list to 50 elements
  while(list.size() > 50) list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```

I can't see the rest of the code. I don't know what list length is before `add` so I'm just guaranteeing it's `<= 50` after with a `while`.

You can specify an initial capacity, if you do, use `51` not `50`. It gives the array an initial size that can hold your `50`, plus the 51st which is in list for a short period before removal.

Comment: why a while? if you think there are more elements use [removeRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange(int,%20int)) no?

Comment: @JordiCastilla because I can't see the rest of the code. I don't know what list length is before `add` so I'm just guaranteeing it's <= 50 after.

Comment: why not remove range? also don't you should define capacity to omtimize memory usage?

Comment: @JordiCastilla because `removeRange` is `protected`. So I would have to subclass `ArrayList`.

Comment: `list.get(list.size()-1)` because `size()` is the actual number of elements in the list, not the current capacity.