# Can't call defined method on Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble with a class I wrote containing an `ArrayList`.
Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AscendingPile {
 public ArrayList<Integer> pile = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
     add(1);
 }};

public void lay(int card) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    int lastCard = pile.get(pile.size() - 1);
    if(card > lastCard || card == lastCard - 10){
        pile.add(card);
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("....");
    }
}
// returns last card on the deck
public int getCard() {
    return pile.get(pile.size() - 1);
}
```

}

Problem is the `lay` method: Instead of defining a new local variable I want the if statement to look something like this:

```
if(card > pile.getCard() || card == pile.getCard() - 10)
```

but IntelliJ says cannot resolve symbol getCard()

How can I change my code to obtain the desired result?

Comment: That's because `getCard()` is not a method defined on `ArrayList`.

Comment: `getCard` is not a method of class `ArrayList`, so you cannot call `getCard` on `pile` which is what you are doing: `pile.getCard()`. Just call `getCard()`, not `pile.getCard()`.

Comment: Also, check this, might be interesting for improving your code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14072408/7709364

Answer (score 1):

> but IntelliJ says cannot resolve symbol getCard()

That is true, ArrayList class has no method called **getCard()**

instead of doing:

```
pile.getCard();
```

do call directly the method of the class **AscendingPile**

```
getCard();
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you very much for the quick response :-)

Answer (score 0):

As already said, just call directly getCard().

I'm also currently coding a card game. Instead of using ArrayList for your deck, i strongly recommend you to use Stack instead. (see documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

Stack provides you useful methods like pop() and push().

Pop removes the object at the top of the stack, just like you're doing now with your getCard() method.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. Unfortunatelly it's an Assignment and we can't use Stack for now. But I'll keep it in mind for future projects!

Comment: I'm coding for assignments too, and i can tell you that taking initiatives is very relevant and well welcomed by teachers in this kind of cases :)