# How to get last object from arraylist in doChangeActivities?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Here is my code, i want to get last object from arraylist to get and set it for PrintActivity, can i?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWbZK.png)

Comment: post code not link (image)

Comment: There's some sites linked to on the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page if you want to include a minimal example of code.  There's also a similar question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687833/how-to-get-the-last-value-of-an-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

```
if(arrayList != null && !arrayList.isEmpty()){  
    arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);
}
```