# How to detect if an element is the last element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, foreach

The code below splits a String based on its position and then puts it into an ArrayList.

So for example, if the String is `"Who Framed Roger Rabbit?"`, then `fragmentMessage` will split the message at every 8th character.

So the ArrayList will look like this:  `[Who Fram, ed Roger,  Rabbit?]`

The elements of the ArrayList are as follows:

1. ArrayList Element 0: `Who Fram`
2. ArrayList Element 1: `ed Roger`
3. ArrayList Element 2: `Rabbit?`

I then have a for-each loop in the main method which iterates over the ArrayList.

How can I detect if I have reached the last element of the array when iterating?

So for example, "*if this is the last element of the array, then print "LAST ELEMENT*".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LastElement {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String message = "Who Framed Roger Rabbit?";
    for (String fragment : fragmentMessage(message)) {
        /*
         * If "fragment" is the last element of the array, then do something
         */
    }
}

private static List<String> fragmentMessage(String message) {
    List<String> fragmentedMessage = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i = i + 8) {
        fragmentedMessage.add(message.substring(i, i + 8));
        System.out.println(fragmentedMessage);
    }

    return fragmentedMessage;
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `for` loop, you could use an `Iterator`, which has a `hasNext()` method.

Comment: Or a traditional for loop, which uses an index.

Comment: There might be better ways, depending on what you actually want to achieve. But you didn't say...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the last value of an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687833/how-to-get-the-last-value-of-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct method to know if you have the last entry of a `List` in a foreach loop.

The easiest would be to use an indexed-loop.

Something like that:

```
    List<String> fragmentMessage = fragmentMessage(message);
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentMessage.size(); i++) {
        String fragment = fragmentMessage.get(i);
        /*
         * If "fragment" is the last element of the array, then do something
         */
        if (i == fragmentMessage.size()-1) {

        }
    }
```

Another option would be an `Iterator`

```
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = fragmentMessage(message).iterator();
        iterator.hasNext();) {
        String fragment = iterator.next();
        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options.

### Use an Iterator:

```
    String message = "Who Framed Roger Rabbit?";
    List<String> fragments = fragmentMessage(message);

    Iterator<String> iterator = fragments.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());

        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("All done!");
        }
    }
```

### Check the index within for/each loop:

```
    for (String str :
            fragments) {

        System.out.println(str);

        // If this item is the last in the list
        if (fragments.indexOf(str) == fragments.size() - 1) {
            System.out.println("All done!");
        }
    }
```

With this method, if you're using strings in your list, just be aware that if there are duplicates, this will not be very accurate.

### Track the index with standard for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(fragments.get(i));

        if (i == fragments.size() - 1) {
            System.out.println("All done!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution looks like this. It is based off **@k5_** answer and credit goes to him/her/other.

I used an if-else statement to ***only*** target the last element.

```
    List<String> fragmentMessage = fragmentMessage(message);
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentMessage.size(); i++) {
        String fragment = fragmentMessage.get(i);
        if (message.isEmpty()) { // Only if message == "".
            System.out.println(createFrame(message));
        } else if (i == fragmentMessage.size() - 1) { // Last element of the array.
            System.out.println(createLastFrame(fragment));
        } else {
            System.out.println(createFrame(fragment)); // Only if message is not the last message.
        }
    }
```

Comment: You considered the case that the last element is also empty?

Comment: @k5_ I can't see of any way the last element can be empty in my code. Is there a way I can privately send you my class?