# How to get last element in ArrayList using Retrofit

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit to fetch data from server. I want to get last element from my arrayList, how to do that?

I already read how to get last element from this quetsion  [How to get the last value of an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687833/how-to-get-the-last-value-of-an-arraylist) but it won't work.

This is my JSON Object http://ipsta.tech/koor.php

This my adapter class

```
    private Context context;

    public KinectAdapter(List<Koor> koorList, Context context) {
        this.koorList = Collections.singletonList(koorList);
        this.context = context;
         
        }

    @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.kinect,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.x.setText(String.valueOf(koorList.get(position).getX()));
    holder.y.setText(String.valueOf(koorList.get(position).getY()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return koorList.size();
        }

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView x,y;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        x = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvX);
        y = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvY);
    }
}
```

And this is my class

```
        koorArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        progressDialog.setTitle("Displaying data");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        progressDialog.show();

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<Koor>> call = apiInterface.getAllDataKoor();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Koor>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Koor>> call, Response<List<Koor>> response) {
                koorArrayList = response.body();
Koor e = koorArrayList.get(koorArrayList.size() - 1);
                    KinectAdapter foodAdapter = new KinectAdapter(e, Kinect.this);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Kinect.this));
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Koor>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Kinect.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
```

this is my Koor class:

```
public class Koor {
    @SerializedName("x")
    private float x;
    @SerializedName("y")
    private float y;

    public Koor(float x, float y, String time) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }
```

and also my output JSONobject is float type.

> Where should i place list.get(list.size()-1; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it in `onResponse` of retrofit call

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Koor>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Koor>> call, Response<List<Koor>> response) 
               {
                koorArrayList = response.body();
                 Koor mKoor = koorArrayList.get(koorArrayList.size() - 1);
                }

          ..............
```

in `mKoor` you have last Koor object from Koor List

Comment: where to use mKoor, it's not fit with the adapter.

Comment: from the question you want to get the last element from ArrayList, use `mKoor` as the last element

Comment: and i want to display it in recyclerview, where did i put that mKoor?

Comment: it's getting error cannot be apllied when i put mKoor in adapter

Comment: then change your adapter constructor

Comment: `foodAdapter =new KinectAdapter(koorArrayList, Kinect.this,mKoor);`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that `Arraylist.size()`

```
        @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Koor>> call, Response<List<Koor>> response) {
                koorArrayList = response.body();
                 Koor e = koorArrayList.get(koorArrayList.size() - 1);
                }
```

or you can simply access in Your adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
--------******************---------------------
 Koor e = koorList.get(koorList.size() - 1);
--------******************---------------------  
    holder.x.setText(String.valueOf(koorList.get(position).getX()));
    holder.y.setText(String.valueOf(koorList.get(position).getY()));
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196226/discussion-on-answer-by-orbit-how-to-get-last-element-in-arraylist-using-retrofi).