# Why does Java not implement a last() method for ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list

I am not asking how to find it, that is already answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687833/how-to-get-the-last-value-of-an-arraylist) other question:

But just going deeper into data-structures in Java, I have found out that the LinkedList implementation has a [getLast()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getLast()) method that is not implemented (I suppose for some reason) in the ArrayList implementation. I could not find any other similar question nor post on Internet explaining it, so I decided to ask it here.

We may agree that it is not elegant the current way of getting the last element from an ArrayList, and usually this implementation is more widely used than LinkedList because it performs better in a wider range of scenarios, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java).

Does anybody know why ArrayList does not implement that method?

Edit: I have edited my question to avoid confusion and opinion based answers. The answer below from Andreas is the one I was looking for, based on facts and references.

Comment: This a question you should take to the person that designed the `List` interface.

Comment: And couldn't that interface be extended as they did for backwards compatibility with the types Date and Calendar when introducing the new Date and Time API in Java 8? I mean to the .from(...) methods they added for mutual conversion. I believe it would not be so complicated to do it so, and don't believe I am the first one wondering it..

Comment: You are welcome to open a [JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0).

Comment: If it's ArrayList you want to use, you can always write your own class, extend ArrayList and write a `getLast()` method. Then reuse that class in your code! Problem solved

Comment: Please note that it's at least simple to create a helper method: http://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/2.0/docs/site/apidocs/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Lists.html#getLast-java.util.List-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Collection classes generally don't implement any public methods that aren't specified by an interface.

[`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does have one method named `trimToSize()` that isn't specified by an interface, but that is a very implementation-specific method.

[`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) doesn't have any methods that isn't specified by an interface.

The *reason* `LinkedList` has a [`getLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getLast--) is shown in the javadoc:

> **Specified by:**
>   [getLast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#getLast--) in interface [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)<[E](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)>

[`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) has most of the same methods as [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) does. The main difference is that `List` has methods for accessing elements by index position, while `Deque` has methods for accessing first / last element.

If you want to work with a list-like collection structure where access to the last element is simple, code to the `Deque` interface, not the `List` interface, and use [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) instead of [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation Andreas, this was actually the type of answer I was looking for, because I could not understand that decision. I did not know the type ArrayDeque, but I believe is very interesting and will explore it further. I appreciate a lot your explanation.

Comment: @Reubems `Deque` is a wastly overlooked member of the Java Collections Framework. Most people just use `List`, because `List` is *good enough* for what they need, when `Deque` would have been a better choice. I'm guilty of that too, but at least I'm aware of its existence, and I have used it, just not of often as I probably should have.

Answer (score 1):

You can access an `ArrayList` last element with a simple `ArrayListName.get(ArrayListName.size() - 1);` because you can access an `ArrayList` element directly with it's index, however in a `linked list` you  have to iterate through every element before you're able to access the last element, this is [most probably] why the engineers created a method to access the last element of a `linked list`.

Comment: That's not the reason at all. The reason [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements the [`getLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getLast--) method is that it has to, since it implements the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface, which [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) doesn't. `LinkedList` doesn't implement any public method that isn't declared by an interface.