# ArrayList of Strings as a parameter and return the last item in the list

Tags: java

I need help on writing this function in Java.. I'm completely stuck
A function: ArrayList of Strings as a parameter and return the
last item in the list.

And I need an function: Arraylist of Strings as a parameter and return the size of the list.

Comment: Have you tried anything?? please add the code.

Comment: Where did you look before? What have you tried before? What didn't workout as expected and why?
Hint: For your second question check the documentation of ArrayList.

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Pleare read through ArrayList documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html.

If you tried anything and encounter an error, please put it in your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last value of an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687833/how-to-get-the-last-value-of-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String getLastItemFromList(ArrayList<String> al) {
    if(al.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    return al.get(al.size()-1);
}

public int getSizeOfList(ArrayList<String> al) {
    return al.size();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Giving you an idea and example

```
import java.util.ArrayList; // import the ArrayList class

ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();

cars.add("Volvo");
cars.add("BMW");
cars.add("Ford");
```

For getting the last item

```
String lastItem(){
    return cars.get(cars.size()-1); //will give you Ford
}
```

For getting the size

```
int numberOfCars(){
   return cars.size();//will give you 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Y u need separate methods ? You can access them by predefined methods of the ArrayList class.

As of what I understood, here is my help !

```
//return Last element
ArrayList<String> stringsList; //assign values

String getLastItem(ArrayList<String> list){
 return list.get(list.size()-1);
}

//return size of the list

int getSize(ArrayList<String> list){
 return list.size();
}
```