# How to output the last name from an array and user input using size.list in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been trying to get the last name in this list in order to output it using `list.size()`. However, `list.size()` only prints the number of names in an array.

Is there a simpler way to explain how I can only record the last name (which is Anna in this case) and print it out when while loop is broken/stopped?

The following names are inputted by the user using scanner utility:

John

Marry

Anderson

Anna

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("")) {
                System.out.println(listOfNames.size());
                break;
            }
            listOfNames.add(input);
        }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687842/19926805) help you?

Comment: Thank you very much, it did help. However, I did not understand the logic and reason behind .size starts with the value 1 and .get starts with the value 0 index in an array. Is it because that the 0 cannot be sized compared to 1 and 0 can be counted instead of sized?

Comment: In nearly every programming language, the 1st item of an array has the index 0. That's just a Language Specification.
The `.size()` method doesn't start with a 1. You could have an empty array, therefor the size would be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to print out the last item in the list.

If that is the case you can simply use the following code:

```
System.out.println(listOfNames.get(listOfNames.size() - 1));
```

Explanation:

`.get()` - this method of Collections Framework (which List is part of) **returns the element at a particular index**. Thus, in the parenthesis, we need to specify the index of the last element in the List.

`.size()` - this method of Collections Framework **returns the number of elements in the List** (in this case). The number we get is how many items is in the List.

Now, in most programming languages and situations **indexes start at a 0**.
If we use the size of the list as the index of the last item, that won't work as the index will be out of bounds.

To use your example, you have 4 names in the List, hence .size() will return `4`.
Since the last index in the listOfNames List in your example is 3 (*because items are indexed 0, 1, 2, 3 - that is all four elements*), there is no item at index 4. So we would get a run-time error.

A very simple and common solution is to simply **subtract 1 from the size**.

Hopefully this helps. It might be confusing at first but you will get used to it as most of the time indexes start at 0.